# Why is my relay node acting as a client, extending and creating circuits simultaneously? i want your help！

Tags: configuration, security, relays, exit-relays

I simulated a small Tor network using Docker.One DA，One Client，Three relays——relay1、relay2、relay3。when I run tor on relay nodes，**I found that the relay node is attempting to create and extend circuits like the picture。**
[image]

**Three relay nodes' torrc files are as pictures：**
[image]

Why does this phenomenon occur? What I want is for only the client to create circuits, with the relay node only acting as a packet forwarder. How should I configure it?